# Type method interfering with database type column problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby on Rails and the [`paths_of_glory` gem](http://github.com/paulca/paths_of_glory)

I need to access the types of achievements that a user accomplishes in order to display a picture along with each particular achievement. When I try to access it via  `@user.achievements.type`, I get an error that says that it wants to return "array" (as in achievements is an array) instead of actually returning the elements in the type column of my database.

Since every ruby object has a method called `type`, my call to access the type column of the database fails. When I try to change the entry in the table, the `paths_of_glory` gem says it needs a type column in order to function properly.

I'm not quite sure where to go from here in order to access that column in the database. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're asking here, but maybe this will help.

For the first thing, `@user.achievements` is an array because you have multiple achievements, and the type method is for individual elements of `@user.achievements` which is why that won't work just like that. You'll have to do something like this:

```
@user.achievements.each do |achievement|
  # Do stuff here
end
```

Regarding the `type` column, type is a reserved column in Rails used specifically for Single Table Inheritance, where multiple Rails models use a single database table. So you can't access it directly. I assume that `paths_of_glory` uses STI in some manner. You can access the model's class with something like `achievement.class`, then if you want just the name of it you can try `achievement.class.to_s`.

```
@user.achievements.each do |achievement|
  model = achievement.class # => MyAwesomeAchievementClass
  @image = model.picture    # You could write some method in the model like this
end
```

Comment: +1 This looks spot on. If you want the type of all of the achievements then you can do `@user.achievements.map(&:type)` which will return an array containing the types of the users achievements or `@user.achievements.first.type` to get the type of the first achievement for the user.

Comment: When I try to run @user.achievements.each do |achievement|, it gives me the error:

The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite Achievement.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.

Comment: Did you try to do anything inside the block or is it erroring on just that line?

Comment: I do stuff in the block, but the error says it comes from that line in particular.

Comment: Can you edit your original post with the block and the error / stack trace? Also, try running it once without doing anything inside the block, just as a control case.